# CORS error accessing ASP.NET Core 8 Web API from Angular front-end

Tags: angular, cors, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-8

I've read every solution and I've tried them all so far, and nothing works.

I have an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API backend and a hybrid .NET 8/Angular 15 front-end. The front-end application can make `GET` requests to the API, but `POST` is blocked by CORS.

I've tried the following in the API:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder => {
                builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:1859");
                builder.WithMethods("GET", "POST");
                builder.AllowAnyHeader();
            });
        });
```

and

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

along with

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder => {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
                builder.AllowAnyMethod();
                builder.AllowAnyHeader();
            });
        });
```

The controller method (I've tried with and without `[EnableCors()]`):

```
[HttpPost] 
public async Task<int> Save(SaveContractRequest req)
```

Angular service method:

```
saveContract(req: SaveContractRequest) {
    return this.http.post<number>(this.settingsSvc.apiEndpoint + ReimbursementEndPoints.CONTRACTS_SAVE, req);
}
```

And yet I always get this error on `POST`:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/evms.api/api/Reimbursement/Contracts/Save' from origin 'http://localhost:1859' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I'm at a loss. I can't get any more permissive than "allow any origin, any header, and any method". Why doesn't this work? Why can't I call a controller with a `POST` method?

Comment: I responded to a similar question here.
[CORS policy angular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77339085/16095321)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `app.UseStaticFiles(); app.UseRouting()` before enabling Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) so that your route is recognized

[image: middleware pipeline]

The order of execution will be

```
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles(); //  here it is
app.UseRouting(); //  here it is

app.UseCors();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Link: [UseCors and UseStaticFiles order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-8.0#usecors-and-usestaticfiles-order)

Comment: Thank you. This worked.

Turns out the issue probably wasn't *exactly* this. I had an unhandled exception occurring in the Save method (was missing a parameter for the stored proc), and *that* error was being masked as a CORS issue. I discovered it when hunting through event logs.

Once I added logging of my own and an exception filter (this API is brand new and I hadn't put in most features like logging), the CORS issue went away and the actual exception was logged.

Answer (score 1):

In Angular you can setup the proxy
create a `proxy.conf.json` folder inside `src` folder in angular app and add the below code (modify the port number and api name)

```
"/yourapi": {
   "target": "http://localhost:PORT/",
   "secure": false,
   "changeOrigin": true
 }
}
```

[Proxy documentation for angular](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server)